# Powershell convert string to array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, foreach

How do I change:

```
$Text = "Apple Pear Peach Banana"
```

to

```
$Text = @("Apple", "Pear", "Peach", "Banana")
```

I am planning to feed the array to a `foreach` loop. The input the user is prompted to enter fruit with a space between (I will use `Read-Host` for that). So then I need to convert a space-separated string to an array for the `foreach` loop.

Thank you...

Comment: You can use `split` like: `$Text -split ' '`

Answer (score 8):

I would use the [`-split` regex operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split), like so:

```
$text = -split $text
```

You can also use it directly in the `foreach()` loop declaration:

```
foreach($fruit in -split $text)
{
    "$fruit is a fruit"
}
```

---

In unary mode (like above), `-split` [defaults to](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7a55bf98b2370ab4817ab2533cb67673053ee446/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/parserutils.cs#L559) splitting on the delimeter `\s+` (1 or more whitespace characters).

This is nice if a user accidentally enters consecutive spaces:

```
PS C:\> $text = Read-Host 'Input fruit names'
Input fruit names: Apple Pear   Peaches  Banana
PS C:\> $text = -split $text
PS C:\> $text
Apple
Pear
Peaches
Banana
```

Comment: Oh this is nice.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use Split()

```
$text = $text.Split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

$Text.Split(' ')

need more characters for answer.

Comment: Say something useful or educative about `$Text.Split(' ')` rather than "need more characters for answer" - there's a reason more characters are required.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies... But how do I add the splited words to an array with double quotes etc...  Is there a  way to do this via read-host... i.e. what the user enters goes into an array? rather than words and spaces?

Comment: Ok  I see now... I can use $Text.Split in the foreach loop....  i.e. foreach ($F in Text.Split(' '))

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = $text -split " "
```

will work, provided that none of your fruit names are two words that you want to keep together.

Comment: Lets just only one word fruits will be used for this exercise.